# django rest framework запрос на токен пользователя

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Есть мобильное приложение которое должно делать запрос с юзернеймом и ему в ответ должен приходить токен если такой пользователь уже существует, иначе пользователь должен добавляться в базу, ему генерится токен, и возвращается.
Как это реализовать?
Вот что у меня есть уже:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
class CreateOrReturnUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = None
        try:
            user = User.objects.filter(username=validated_data['username'])
        except:
            user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return Token.objects.get(user=user)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш сериалайзер из вопроса не будет вызывать из исключение, т.к. `objects.filter` просто вернет пустой кверисет при отсутствии пользователя с переданным `username`, метод `create` можно не перегружать и обойтись одним условием во view

```
class UserView(APIView):

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')

        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        else:
            serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user = serializer.save()
            else:
                return Response(serializer.errors)

        token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response(str(token))
```

Если юзер уже есть в базе то путь валидации и создания пользователя пропускается и в конце возвращается уже имеющийся или новый токен.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, но чувствую что это очень грязный код

```
class Asd(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = CreateOrReturnUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            t = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        else:
            user = User.objects.filter(username=dict(serializer.initial_data)["username"])
            t = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        return Response(str(t), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```